# Find the value of $A$m if $\cos A \sin (A-\frac{\pi}{6})$ is maximum

Tags: trigonometry

Using derivative

$$\frac{d}{dA}=(\cos A)(\cos (A-\frac{\pi}{6})) +(\sin (A-\frac{\pi}{6}))(-\sin x)=0$$

$$\cos (2A-\frac{\pi}{6})=0$$

$$2A-\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$A=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

I just want to know, is there a way to solve this without using calculus. I am fairly confident there is. I just can’t find it.

Comment: Use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos (A) \sin\left(A-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\\ = \frac 12 \bigg[\sin\left(2A -\frac{\pi}{6} \right) + \sin\left(\frac{-\pi}{6}\right)\bigg] $$

Clearly, to maximize this we need $\sin\left(2A - \frac{\pi}{6} \right)=1 \implies A=\frac{\pi}{3}+n\pi$